# ntlm implementation in java?

Tags: java, swing, exception, weblogic, ntlm

I know that I can set proxyhost and proxyport for the java application 
to work through a normal proxy server. But (at least) on corporate 
networks there are authentication schemes on proxies. I am using 
URLConnection to download a zip file from internet inside 
corporate network. I am using Weblogic as server for my application.
I am aware of HTTPClient that claims to deal with the 
NTLM proxy, but how? I have found no 
examples nor tutorials that deal with this.

I have been searching web really for a while now and have found out that 
NTLM proxy authentication is Microsoft's authentication scheme that has 
no public specification? Is it really true that Java is not capable of 
dealing with corporate networks (or corporate proxies)? Do I really need 
to go to the JSP ect. road on this one?

1. Is it possible to use java application client to access url for download a file
   through NTLM proxy server? How? Example would really be appreciated.

**this is the error that I get**

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.available(PlainSocketImpl.java:428)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:217)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:321)
at weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream.read(KeepAliveStream.java:86)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
at be.azvub.ext.bcfidownloder.Download.downloadZipFile(Download.java:131)
```

Comment: NTLM does have a specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236621(v=prot.13).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried  [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)? this is an solution in sourceforge.. it works quite well.

Comment: It is written in Python . I don't know how to use it.
My application should run on Weblogic.
Could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

I know that [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) provides a NTLM implementation, but I am nut sure if it can be combined with HTTPClient. I also believe that Sun/Oracle Java 6 includes a NTLM implementation.

It looks like this [page](http://oaklandsoftware.com/papers/ntlm.html) (from 2007) provides an overview of NTLM support from Java.